# Function composition different behaviour of andThen and compose

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I'm currently going through [Scala with Cats](https://books.underscore.io/scala-with-cats/scala-with-cats.html) and enjoying it a lot.
In Exercise 4.1.2 (Getting Func-y) we are tasked to implement `map` using the methods `pure` and `flatMap` only.

The code for reference:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  def flatMap[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => F[B]): F[B]

  def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
    ???
}
```

My thinking was as follows:
For the first parameter of `flatmap` we just pass `value`.
For the second parameter, we have the function `func: A => B` and a method `pure`, which, after eta expansion, has the form `pure: A => F[A]`. Therefore, we compose `pure` with `func`, i.e. we pass `pure _ compose func`, where `pure _` eta expands `pure`.

`map` would then look like this:

```
def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
  flatMap(value)(pure _ compose func)
```

However, this didn't work and produced the following error:

```
[error] 7:35: type mismatch;
[error]   A => B|scala.Nothing
[error]     flatMap(value)(pure _ compose func)
[error]                                   ^
[info] A => B <: ? => Nothing?
[info] false
[error] 6:30: parameter value func in method map is never used
[error]   def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
[error]                              ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

To my surprise, using `func andThen pure` for the second parameter does compile.

`map` defined like this compiles:

```
def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
  flatMap(value)(func andThen pure)
```

I'm surprised because I assumed that for two functions `f: A => B` and `g: B => C`, the following would hold:

`f andThen g` is equivalent to `a => g(f(a))` and 
`g compose f` is equivalent to `a => g(f(a))`, 
therefore `f andThen g` and `g compose f` are equivalent.

**What's the reason that this doesn't hold in general and in this example?**

I used scala version 2.13.8 above.

I thought, maybe the problem relates to the eta expansion of the `pure` method. I found several questions relating to `compose` and `andThen` methods as well as eta expansion, but they didn't answer my question.

I found a scala 3 reference entry about [Automatic Eta Expansion](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/eta-expansion.html), so I tried my luck in scala 3.2.1:

```
trait Monad[F[_]]:
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  def flatMap[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => F[B]): F[B]

  def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
    flatMap(value)(pure compose func)
```

Notice, how we don't need the underscore after `pure` anymore (it will be deprecated at some point in the future) because of the automatic eta expansion mentioned in the scala 3 reference article above.

However, this also throws an error:

```
-- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: --------------------------------------------------------
7 |    flatMap(value)(pure compose func)
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                   Found:    A => F[Any]
  |                   Required: A => F[B]
  |
  |                   where:    F is a type in trait Monad with bounds <: [_] =>> Any
```

(In the where clause, I don't understand what kind of upper bound `[_] =>> Any` should be.)

But, again, `map` using `func andThen pure` compiles.

Based on the error message, I now believe that the compiler can somehow not infer the correct type because... of the type parameters? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes eta-expansion is sometimes confusing for the compiler and you have to clarify things yourself.

In Scala 2 I managed to make your code compile with:

```
def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
  flatMap(value)((pure[B](_)).compose(func))
```

because `method _` doesn't always work and `method(_)` is more in your face (you still have to define `[B]` to avoid inferring it to something silly like `Any` or `Nothing`).

In Scala 3 it works slightly better:

```
def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
  flatMap(value)((pure[B] _).compose(func))
```

or even

```
def map[A, B](value: F[A])(func: A => B): F[B] =
  flatMap(value)(pure[B] compose func)
```

works - you only have to provide `[B]` explicitly so that it wont attempt to combine `Nothing => F[Nothing]` with `A => B`. Currently it cannot be avoided as compiler:

- tries to infer types for `pure` before calling `compose` on eta-expanded method
- since no restriction yet applies, it infers it to `Nothing`
- only then it can infer types on `.compose` which takes `A => B` value
- however it already inferred that it should be something that is `? => Nothing`

so this particular problem comes from compiler not inferring whole expression at once but doing it in chunks.

Comment: In Scala 2 `flatMap(value)(pure[B] _ compose func)` works as well. So, as you correctly wrote, I just have to give the compiler a hint. Wonderful!